# Compile iReport 4.0.2 from sources with NetBeans 6.5.1 java.io.IOException

Tags: compilation, ireport, ioexception, netbeans6.5

I am trying to compile iReport 4.0.2 with NetBeans 6.5.1. On the iReport forums it says that this is the NetBeans platform to which it is compatible.

However, I get this error when compiling the project:

> C:\Program Files\NetBeans 6.5.1\harness\suite.xml:106: The following
>   error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\Program Files\NetBeans
>   6.5.1\harness\build.xml:98: java.io.IOException: No definition of netbeans.dest.dir in
>   V:\iReport-4.0.2-src\iReport-4.0.2-src\jasperreports-components

This is the line 106 in suite.xml

```
<subant target="netbeans" buildpath="${modules.sorted}" inheritrefs="false" inheritall="false"/>
```

This is the line 98 in build.xml:

```
>
```

... it is basically closing an xml start tag (parseprojectxml) - this is the context of the line (the single angle bracket):

```
<parseprojectxml
        project="."
        publicpackagesproperty="public.packages"
        friendsproperty="friends"
        javadocpackagesproperty="module.javadoc.packages"
        moduledependenciesproperty="module.dependencies"
        moduleclasspathproperty="module.classpath"
        publicpackagejardir="${public.package.jar.dir}"
        modulerunclasspathproperty="module.run.classpath"
        classpathextensionsproperty="class.path.extensions"
    >
        <testtype name="unit"
                  folder="test.unit.folder"
                  runtimecp="test.unit.runtime.cp"
                  compilecp="test.unit.compile.cp"
                  compiledep="test.unit.testdep"/>
        <testtype name="qa-functional"
                  folder="test.qa-functional.folder"
                  runtimecp="test.qa-functional.runtime.cp"
                  compilecp="test.qa-functional.compile.cp"
                  compiledep="test.qa-functional.testdep"/>
    </parseprojectxml>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was somehow solved by opening each module in NetBeans IDE, then opening the properties dialog and clicking OK for each module. I restarted the IDE and then I managed to run the project.

If someone can exaplain what caused the problem and why my actions managed to solve it... I would like to have an explanation for this behavior.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the above problem in iReports trunk version (> 4.6.0). After marking off read only mode (which the solution of previous answer do), you might need to add

```
<nbmproject2:property name="netbeans.dest.dir" value="nbplatform.${nbplatform.active}.netbeans.dest.dir" xmlns:nbmproject2="http://www.netbeans.org/ns/nb-module-project/2"/>
```

in jasperreports-extensions and MongoDbPlugin.

Gaurav J

Answer (score 0):

I can compile ireport with NetBeans success.I think you must modify file with name "platform-private.properties"